# Union type in Julia

Tags: types, julia, multiple-dispatch

I am wondering about types in Julia, more specific `Union`. For instance, I have made a function where I add the length of my input `a` into a vector `len_a`. If `a` is of type `VariableRef`I want the length to be 1. I write it like this;

```
function add_length!(a::VariableRef,lenComp::Vector, i::Int)

    len_a[i] = 1.0; 
end
```

However, if `a` is not of type `VariableRef` I want it to take the length. So I am wondering if I should do as I have done below, like defining a new type by using `Union`:

`NotVariableRef = Union{Vector, NonlinearExpression, QuadExpr, AffExpr}`

```
function add_length!(a::NotVariableRef,len_a::Vector, i::Int) 

    len_a[i] = length(a)
end
```

or if I should do it like this;

```
function add_length!(a::Any,len_a::Vector, i::Int) 

    len_a[i] = length(a)
end
```

What is the "right" way of doing it? And is this: `len_a::Vector, i::Int)` alright or should I have something like `len_a::Vector{Int}, i::Int64)`. I am a bit confused by this type system.

Comment: If you are storing lengths inside `len_a`, then presumably you would write `len_a[i] = 1`, not `len_a[i] = 1.0`, since lengths are integers, not floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia is [using multiple dispatch](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/) to select a particular method to be executed.

For multiple dispatch among available methods Julia will use the one with the most concrete type. Hence there is no need to define something like `NotVariableRef`. Normally you would do:

```
function add_length!(len_a, a::VariableRef, i)
    len_a[i] = 1.0
end
function add_length!(len_a, a, i)
    len_a[i] = length(a)
end
```

With this code the appropriate method will be chosen depending on the type of `a`. Note that by Julia convention I moved the `len_a` parameter to the front as this is the one being mutated (usually `...!` functions mutate the first parameter). I also removed the types as they are not necessary. However if you need I would rather use abstract types for parameters of your function such as `AbstractVector` and `Integer` to have a greater API flexibility.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I thought `i::int` etc. would help with the speed or make the code "safer". That is not the case or?

Comment: No, the type only matters for performance when you define data structures (`struct`) or data containers with parametric types (eg. `Vector`). In case of function parameters types are efficiently handled by Julia compiler. Avoiding writing overly-specific types is also recommended in Julia Style Guide https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/ . For a detailed discussion on performance and types for containers see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/.